# LM317 vs Rheostat

Tags: lm317, rheostat

I am trying to limit the voltage to a 12 volt , 25 watt silicone heating pad. I am trying to decide between a rheostat and an LM317 voltage regulator which I would control using an external potentiometer. I need to be able to deliver 2.1 amps at 12 volt to power this device. I imagine rheostats for controlling DC voltage are outdated technology which are not used much ?

I have a constant 12 volt supply and i want to be able to modulate the intensity of the heat produced by the heater pad by controlling the voltage it is provided.

Comment: Why? Are you trying to achieve constant power? From what supply? Is the supply voltage constant? If so the rheostat and LM317 will do the same job and waste the same amount of energy as heat. If you care about energy use you'd use a converter.

Comment: If your supply voltage is fixed you would only need a fixed resistor.

Comment: @Transistor the supply voltage is constant 12 volts. I want to be able to vary the voltage i output between 0-12 volts. I am not trying to achieve constant power. I want to vary power with voltage.

Comment: PWM (pulse-width modulating the power to the heater) would be a better way to do that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so would you recommend perhaps an H-bridge motor speed controller ?

Comment: No reason for a H-bridge controller since you don't need to reverse the current through the heating element.  A simple adjustable PWM circuit controlling a suitably-rated MOSFET will do the trick.  I'll also note that while you can find rheostats in the power range to do this, an LM317 will not be able to handle this amount of current.

Comment: @vir so basically something like this will do the trick - https://www.amazon.com/Onyehn-Controller3V-Control-Switch-Dimmer/dp/B07GP72BWV/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=dimmer+pwm&qid=1633634039&sr=8-4

Comment: Yes, that should work.  PWM frequency isn't an issue here since you're driving an essentially purely resistive load with a thermal time constant many orders of magnitude longer than any conceivable PWM frequency.